Gazebo - Add files to GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH at runtime
I am working on a project in ROS2 and Gazebo where I have to stream images at runtime and load them onto textures to place into the world as a robot moves around.
From ROS2 I have managed without problem to load images onto planes and position them in the world. However: Gazebo only recognizes the images if they're placed in a directory on the GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH BEFORE Gazebo is launched. If I try to add an image to models/my_plane/textures/ (for instance) while Gazebo is running, it doesn't acknowledge them until I restart Gazebo.
I am sure there must be a way to reload GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH during runtime or place files in some dynamic directory or implement some other workaround for this issue - but I haven't been able to find one yet.
Any insights, explanations, or code examples on how to use files added to GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH at runtime would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
(using gazebo-11, ros2-humble and python)
